# time out while checking out a connection from connectin pool while accessing MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I tried to use axios to call my function in go lang api. but did show me this error:

timed out while checking out a connection from connection pool: context canceled; maxPoolSize: 10000, connections in use by cursors: 0, connections in use by transactions: 0, connections in use by other operations: 1

I tried to change the maxPoolSize: 100, 200 and 10000. but didn't work.
my route works fine, I have this problem just when I try to call route for axios.

my request in axios:

```
export async function validLogin(email, password) { 

  const data = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
  let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  };

  await axios.post('http://localhost:1323/profile/valid', data, headers)
  .then(response => {
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
  });

}
```

the local that calls function:

```
async function validateLogin() {
   if (password !== "" && email !== "") {
      const result = await validLogin(email, password)
      alert(result)
      if (result === "ok")
        setValidUser(true)
    }

  };
```

Comment: Are both your apps (front and back) running on port 1323? If not, have you setup your development reverse proxy to proxy calls to the backend? Can you `curl http://localhost:1323/profile/valid`?

Comment: BTW you are not returning anything so your alert will always show undefined. You need to `return await axios.post...`)

Comment: The error sounds like it's coming from a MongoDB or its driver (Go code which works as a client). Your code does not show working with MongoDB explicitly. Can you use this information to trace your problem further? It's 100% not connected to axios.

Comment: Basically, you should first make sure operations on MongoDB work w/o "the server" part, just in a standalone Go program which, say, runs 100 goroutines concurrently with each querying the DB. Once you have this done, you can move on to wiring an HTTP server to this logic and after that—working with this server from JS on the front-end side.

Comment: the front is on port 3000 and the back is 1323. the post route is working perfectly I'm calling it through postman. and it works just fine.